# Yii ajax query return nothing

Tags: php, sql, yii

I want to check is null or empty result in my DB, create this query

```
$query = "SELECT smtp_login FROM tbl_users WHERE id=". $id. " AND (smtp_login IS NULL OR TRIM(smtp_login)='')";
$list = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->query();
foreach($list as $item){
for($i=0;$i<count($item);$i=$i+1)
{
if(is_null($item[$i]) & $item[$i]=='') { echo 'True'; }
else { echo 'False'; }
}
}
```

When item is null all is ok, getting True value, but when it isn't returned just empty popup not False.

Comment: add this in javascript and all fine, but not good if(output === null || output === ''){alert('False')}
            else
            {
             alert(output);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Use **or(||)** instead of **and(&)**

```
 if(is_null($item[$i]) || $item[$i]=='') { echo 'True'; }
```

Comment: what your exact objective give me some teat case .edit with some input and output you want

Comment: try to print that $item variable before you check

Comment: if its empty you get True by this code am i correct

Comment: it's can't be empty, i checked in sql and value is 123.

Answer (score 0):

Use `queryAll()` instead of `query()`. `query()` returns a single record, but `queryAll()` - all data matching criteria.